# How can I fix the unknown format error in my image segmentation model?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, metrics

I am currently studying on my histopathologic nuclei image segmentation model using U-Net architecture in Python. I built the model, and got the prediction, but I have a problem with model evaluation. My model has 4 classes, and I want to plot the ROC, AUC curve of my model, but it produces error.

***The error is:***

> ValueError: unknown format is not supported

*It gives the error for y_test_cat when I try to plot the ROC curve like in the code below it gives this error.*

***I used to_categorical function here for y_train and y_test.***

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
train_masks_cat = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=n_classes)
y_train_cat = train_masks_cat.reshape((y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[2], n_classes))
```

```
test_masks_cat = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=n_classes)
y_test_cat = test_masks_cat.reshape((y_test.shape[0], y_test.shape[1], y_test.shape[2], n_classes))
```

```
n_classes=4
```

I tried to make y_test_cat integer to solve the problem, but it does not work, and now I don't know how to fix this error.

```
y_test_cat = y_test_cat.astype(int)
```

***It produces the specified error in this code block.***

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
# probs from log preds
probs = np.exp(preds[:,1])
# Compute ROC curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test_cat, probs, pos_label=1)

# Compute ROC area
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print('ROC area is {0}'.format(roc_auc))
```

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([-0.01, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.01])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
```

The entire error can be seen here:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-c5f976362ec4> in <module>
      3 probs = np.exp(preds[:,1])
      4 # Compute ROC curve
----> 5 fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(X_test1, probs, pos_label=1)
      6 
      7 # Compute ROC area

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    911 
    912     """
--> 913     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
    914         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    915 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    689     if not (y_type == "binary" or
    690             (y_type == "multiclass" and pos_label is not None)):
--> 691         raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    692 
    693     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)

ValueError: unknown format is not supported
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test_cat, probs, pos_label=1)`, check your `y_test_cat`. Check the type of this variable.

Comment: I converted it to integer @m.i.cosacak

Comment: Did it solve the problem? But I do not think it is about converting to integer.

Comment: I've searched it on previous questions in stackoverflow, then I tried it, but it did not solve the problem. That's why I am looking for a new solution for this @m.i.cosacak

Comment: Please read about [MRE from here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should provide minimum requirements to reproduce your error. Then, someone may help you.